# Mac Terminal Command not Found

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I've been using my mac and I realized that some basic commands seem to be missing. I have tried commands including : ping, traceroute, reboot, halt
and they all show
-bash: [SomeCommand]: Command not found

I have installed Xcode and the CommandLineTools package as well. Can somebody help me resolve this problem?  Thank you!

Below are some informations of my terminal:

> HenrydeMacBook-Air:~ bumpwymac$ $PATH
>   -bash: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/XCrySDen-1.5.24-bin-semishared:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/XCrySDen-1.5.24-bin-semishared/scripts:/Applications/XCrySDen-1.5.24-bin-semishared/util: No such file or directory

Thank you!

Comment: I think this belongs on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ping , halt and reboot are all in /sbin. I think your PATH lacks of "/sbin". Here are mine :

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:***/sbin***:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/go/bi‌​n:.:/Users/frank/work/bin/:/Users/frank/work/bin/:/usr/local/go/bin:
>   No such file or directory